# Router events cause an error while being used on the constructor Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm facing this issue, I tried to convert it to a function but the `states` didn't work as I expected. How can I solve this? I want to create a loading effect when switching routes without causing such issues:

```
react-dom.development.js?ac89:67 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
        at Loading (webpack-internal:///./components/loading.js:83:9)
        at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:58:27)
        at StyleRegistry (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/stylesheet-registry.js:231:34)
```

here is my code:

```
import Router from "next/router";
import { Component } from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";

export default class Loading extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        loader: false
      }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      // Some page has started loading
      Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", (url) => {
        this.setState({ loader: true });
      });
         // Some page has finished loading
         Router.onRouteChangeComplete = (url) => {
          this.setState({ loader: false });
        };
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){

  }  

  render() {
    return(
      <Loader loading={this.state.loader} />
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried:

```
import Router from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";

export default function Loading (){
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);

  // Some page has started loading
  Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", (url) => {
      setLoader(true);
  });
  // Some page has finished loading
  Router.onRouteChangeComplete = (url) => {
      setLoader(false);
  };

  return <Loader loading={loader} />;
}
```

Comment: _"I tried to convert it to a function"_ - Can you show your attempt at converting it to a function component?

Comment: thank you, I think it worked this time <3, the problem was with `onRouteChangeError` which caused me all the trouble

Comment: no, It Didn't work.  now I see the same problem. are React states not created until the DOM load or before?

Comment: You need to move the code you had in `componentDidMount` inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you had in `componentDidMount` needs to be moved inside a `useEffect`. In addition, the subscriptions to the router events need to be cleaned up when the component unmounts to prevent the error you're seeing.

It's also recommended to use the `router` instance from the `useRouter` hook rather than accessing the global router object directly.

Your function component should roughly look like the following.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";

export default function Loading () {
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChangeStart = (url) => {
            setLoader(true);
        };
        const handleRouteChangeComplete = (url) => {
            setLoader(false);
        };

        router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChangeStart);
        router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChangeComplete);

        // When the component unmounts, unsubscribe from the router events with the `off` method
        return () => {
            router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChangeStart);
            router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChangeComplete);
        };
    }, [router]);
  
    return <Loader loading={loader} />;
}
```